# How to find the Java resource leaks if the file/connection resources are not being closed at runtime.?

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, inputstream, filereader

1. Is it possible to find the Unclosed resource streams in code at
   runtime?
2. Is there any tool or any method to find if any file/connection
   resources are leaking and are not closed properly by the developer.
   I want to know this at runtime of the program with Heap Dump or any
   other method available. Please let me know if you know any tools or
   library available.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same question. I would have framed it the same way. How can I reframe it to meet Stack Overflow guidelines?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some profilers offer the capability to detect resource leaks. In [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), for example, there is a "Files" probe that shows you which files are still open

[image]

The same functionality is available for sockets and processes.

Another common source of resource leaks are JDBC connections which are handled by the JDB probe:

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.